# PDO bindParam with $_POST not working

Tags: php, select, post, pdo

I've been searching and searching and trying all kinds of stuff and I just can't get this working right. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I'm very new to PDO and trying to figure that out with plenty of other things.

I can get the following to work IF I manually submit a value instead of trying to bind it, but I want to use the placeholder. I've gotten a value of 'Array' back, sometimes MySQL responds with :name causing invalid syntax... I've tried rearranging the values for bind and I just can't get it to give me back the value. I have an insert portion of this and that works fine, but I'm messing something up here and the query itself.

I appreciate any direction you can help me with. This is driving me crazy:

NOTE: Since this is only a test, all the db contains is name and phone columns (will expand as I get past these obsticles).

```
    <?php
    # VARs
    $host = "MYHOST";
    $db = "MYDB";
    $user = "MYUSER";
    $pw = "MYPW";

    # pdo options/attributes
    $opts = array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    # data source name
    $dsn = "mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db;

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head><title>Test</title>

    </head>
    <body>

    <h3>Test</h3>
    <p>Pull data using PDO</p>
    <form method="POST" action="test.php"><input type="text" name="name"><input type="submit" value="Search"></form><br /><br />
    <hr />

    <? 
        try {

            $DBH = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pw, $opts);
            # $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

            $STH = $DBH->query('SELECT name, phone FROM directory WHERE name LIKE :name');

            $STH->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name']);

            $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
                echo $row['name'] . "\n" . $row['phone'] . "<br />";
            }
        }

        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.<br />";
            echo $e->getMessage();
            # file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
        }
    ?>

    <hr />

    </body>
    </html>
```

**- - - - - - - - - - - - - RESOLVED ANSWER - - - - - - - - - - - - -**

**- - - - - - - - - - - - - RESOLVED ANSWER - - - - - - - - - - - - -**

Thanks to the responses below, here is the correction to my query and pdo layout:

```
    <? 
        try {

            $DBH = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pw, $opts);
            # $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

            ####-------Changed query to prepare
            $STH = $DBH->prepare('SELECT name, phone FROM directory WHERE name LIKE :name'); 

            ####-------using bindValue instead of bindParam
            ####-------also using % for wildcards to help with LIKE query (would only give specific search back without)
            $STH->bindValue(':name', '%' . $_POST['name'] . '%'); 

            ####-------was missing execute (had query above instead of prepare)
            $STH->execute();

            $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
                echo $row['name'] . "\n" . $row['phone'] . "<br />";
            }
        }

        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.<br />";
            echo $e->getMessage();
            # file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: use `prepare()` not `query()`

Comment: `name LIKE :name`? Why like? You're doing an extact string match, presumably. `name = :name is far easier to understand... unless you're planning on allowing username wildcard matching at some point.

Comment: Hello @MarcB - It's a search field, so I do need it to look for non-specific queries.

Comment: I don't think you can use bindParam with LIKE,try bindValue.

Comment: @Fred - Hi Fred... I tried that and it acts the same (only gives me a specific pull if the name fully matches). I'll have to toy around with that next though. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Also try changing $_POST['name'] to "$".$_POST['name']."$" [Examples](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: Tried that @Fred and it didn't fix it. I actually tried a search and didn't get anything this time. I also tried placing that in the query directly but that just gave me an error around NULL and then my search. No results though.

Comment: @Fred - plus 1'ing you on the $ wildcard recommendation because you made me look. I used **$STH->bindValue(':name', '%' . $_POST['name'] . '%');** after researching the wildcards and % worked. Thanks for the nudge! You're also correct in stating that bindParam doesn't like the wildcards (at least not how I used it here).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot `$STH->execute();`

It should come after `$STH->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name']);`

You should also use `$DBH->prepare();` instead of `$DBH->query();`

Comment: This straightened me out. Thanks a lot @Mister Melancholy - VERY Appreciated. Now on to the path of finding out why my LIKE statement isn't pulling all queries related to a show request (e.g. Bill should pull several Bill rows, but will only give me to specific row of Bill - doesn't send back Bill Bowa).
Thanks Again!

Comment: PS. Will also upvote you as soon as I have enough rep to do so! Thanks again

Comment: I'd have stayed and helped with your MYSQL problem, but I was running late for work. Glad everything got resolved though; that's all that really matters.

Comment: Thanks @Mister Melancholy ...I appreciate that. I'll have some more soon to as I'm building a class and want to see if I'm doing it right (getting the update part of it together first).